# Sending POST request: missing trailing slash in url triggers redirecting GET request

Tags: php, http-post, postman

I tried to send the following POST request to `https://myurl.com/directoryname` in JSON format:

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test2"
}
```

And the `index.php` file on my server has the following to debug:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

$raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($raw_data);
```

But when I try to `var_dump()` and `echo` these variables, I got:

> request method: **string(3) "GET"**
>
> raw_data: **string(0) ""**
>
> data: **NULL**

There does not seem to be any problem with these codes in PHP, so I assume the problem must be in the way that I send this request.

Comment: Put in `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);`, and check if that actually says POST.

Comment: @CBroe It returns GET, but I have selected POST in postman. However, if I send the same request to "postman-echo.com/post", it works fine. Is it about anything I should add in my PHP file to make it process POST request?

Comment: Most likely explanation is that your system has responded to the POST request with a redirect, that the client (postman) follows up on by making a GET request for the same URL. What URL are you sending this to, and how is that set up?

Comment: @CBroe It is a remote cloud server that I tried to set up a backend API for registration   in an app on iOS. It is basically an index.php file in a directory. I have updated the code above to show more information about this index.php file.

Comment: _“It is basically an index.php file in a directory.”_ - so, again, what URL are you actually sending the request to? Are you targetting the index.php file directly? Or just the directory? If you send this to `https://example.com/directoryname`, then you will most likely get a “trailing slash redirect”. The solution would be to send it to `https://example.com/directoryname/` then (or to the index.php directly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from @CBore in the comment, sending a request to `https://myurl.com/directoryname` (without the trailing slash) will trigger a redirect to `https://myurl.com/directoryname/` and thus make a GET request.

A POST request should be sent to `https://myurl.com/directoryname/` (with the trailing slash), or `https://myurl.com/directoryname/filename.php`.

More detailed explanation about slashes in url can be found here: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is perfectly fine.
Double check the URL to which the request is going.

Debug using echo statement

try to send the data using form-data option.

use print_r($_POST); and verify once

Answer (score 0):

Per their default, it starts with GET, so you wanna make sure you use POST method.
Since I can't see how you sent raw data, I would recommend you look into their documentation here:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#selecting-request-methods

You could also test their REST api here for posting and getting methods to see what data comes and goes:
https://docs.postman-echo.com/?version=latest

Here's what I got with what I ran it (do notice the parameters I used):
https://gyazo.com/a5f712fdd9c7abce606f9f0ba6248e74

Comment: The same POST request works fine if I send it to "postman-echo.com/post". But if I `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);` in my PHP file on my server, it still returns 'GET'.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be no error in that script i think you should check your server